# git bisect with additional patch

Tags: git, git-bisect

Let's say I have these revisions:

- `rev 1` introduces bug #1
- `rev 2` possibly introduces bug #2
- `rev 3` possibly introduces bug #2
- `rev 4` possibly introduces bug #2
- `rev 5` fixes bug #1

To verify where bug #2 occured, bug #1 needs to be fixed.

Can the revision where bug #2 first occured be determined during a single `git bisect` run, possibly through manually appling the `rev 5` patch on each bisect step? Would manually patching interfere a bisect?

Comment: see `Automatically bisect with temporary modifications` in the bisect documentation.

Comment: Adding a link to the docs example section that Torek mentions: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_examples

@torek If you posted that link as an answer, I'd vote for it :)

Comment: @ncoghlan: I'd basically just be reproducing the man-page example (SO answers aren't supposed to be just-a-link)...

Answer (score 5):

When you reach the region that requires the hot-fix patch(rev 5 in your ex.), just run:

```
git cherry-pick --no-commit hot-fix
```

Then continue bisecting normally.

Answer (score 4):

After actually reading the docs, something like this might work (per bisect step):

```
git cherry-pick [patch-rev]
git reset --hard
git bisect [good/bad]
```

Comment: this sounds ok but is it possible that the fix could be amended into the last commit to avoid doing tis step by step?

Comment: For automated bisection, combine `git cherry-pick --no-commit` (instead of `git-merge`) with the `hot-fix` example mentioned in the comments on the question.